# How to get range of value in jquery array collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here i used array collection:

```
var arr = [23, 24, 34, 43, 53, 34];
```

I want to get the value between 21 to 46. i don't want to looping or indexing to the array value.

is there any function to get like `arr.range(21,46)` ? how can i get it ?

Comment: Without - iterating , you can't. What do you think `range` will do behind the scenes?

Comment: Write it statically :P

Comment: @RayonDabre Put it as an answer, I'll upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

try

```js
var arr = [23, 24, 34, 43, 53, 34]; //your input array
var min = 21; //your min value
var max = 46; //your max value

//check each item `value` in the array one by one
var newArray = arr.filter(function(value) {
  //if value falls in min and max then return true else false
  return (value >= min && value <= max);
})

console.log(newArray);
```

```html
<!-- Results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you see the implementation of `filter`, You are going to see `for(var ....` for sure...

Comment: @Tushar explained, I thought it was too simple :)

Comment: @RayonDabre I thought OP meant he didn't want to use a for loop and index based itearation

Comment: I have just tried to improve code,you are free to rollback if its not acceptable

Comment: @gurvinder372 That's exactly what they meant. That comment was clearly just being pedantic. This answer is spot on.

Comment: i think filter also getting iterate only

Answer (score 1):

You can use **filter** function.

```
function getValues(value) {
  return value >= 21 && value <= 46;
}

var arr = [23, 24,34,43,53,34].filter(getValues);
```

Comment: i think getvalues also function which is iterate each time only... can you give any other solution ?

Comment: @Harin, you can't iterate over an array without, well, iterating it... See the paradox of the thing?!